How to update system installation of python (setuptools) on Ubuntu
I get the following warning from AWS Inspector on the Ubuntu machine:

CVE-2024-6345 - setuptools, setuptools Finding ID:
arn:aws:inspector2:eu-west-1:355370908234:finding/348da83463e3a933ffccae7dcffeb1cc
A vulnerability in the package_index module of pypa/setuptools
versions up to 69.1.1 allows for remote code execution via its
download functions. These functions, which are used to download
packages from URLs provided by users or retrieved from package index
servers, are susceptible to code injection. If these functions are
exposed to user-controlled inputs, such as package URLs, they can
execute arbitrary commands on the system. The issue is fixed in
version 70.0.

As I understand I now need install version 70. My assumption is that this is related to the system wide pre-installed version of python/pip on my machine. What's the correct way to update setuptools for the system wide python installation on Ubuntu?
Running this:
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade setuptools

gives well known error externally-managed-environment:

error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed ╰─> To install Python
packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install...
See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python
installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at
the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing
--break-system-packages. hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

This command:
$ sudo apt install python3-setuptools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (68.1.2-2ubuntu1.1).
python3-setuptools set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

doesn't install v70, it says 68 is the most recent one.

you can download the setuptools from pypi as a whl file for the version you want and then install it in the system python environment,

@sahasrara62, thanks, so pypi specifies the latest version of setuptools as 75, do you maybe know the reason why apt package falls so behind it? you can download the setuptools from pypi as a whl file for the version you want and then install it in the system python environment - intead I could probably go with the option of using --break-system-packages, which as I undersatnd is the same as what you're suggesting, but I'd like to avoid that

@MaxKoretskyi Probably the supported version they support till now is  69.1.1 , if you dont want to use this then a viritualenv and use python from that to whole system can solve problem, but as of now if you want to use system only then you need to wait for them to provide support for upgraded setuptools

okay, thanks, aws inspector checks global packages, so I need to update global packages,

The system-provided Python is not suitable for development. It exists to make your operating system work properly, not to provide Python for your own use. Packages that can be installed by the system package manager (especially on certain distros) are out of date all the time, because the point is that the distro is reviewing the code to ensure it's safe for a system-level installation, possibly applying its own patches, etc. If you want up-to-date Setuptools direct from the source, use a virtual environment (which you should have anyway).

At any rate, the CVE you describe is not very meaningful. Python package installation is notoriously insecure in the first place; even pip download can end up running arbitrary code from setup.py (and it's been like that for almost the entire history of Pip, and is still not fixed in 24.3.1 even for sdists that conform to all the latest standards.)
